What is Meant by Metallic Atoms being "Isotropic"?
Many resources online say that metals are isotropic, in that they have the same properties in all directions, and it is because of their metallic bonds; because metal atoms are treated as point charges, they can closely pack without regard to the location of their electron orbitals.
However, I am looking at it from a Gen. Chem. understanding, and even if the d-orbital is delocalized, I assume that the higher energy s-orbital is what remains to make the metal atoms "isotropic." is this why metallic atoms are isotropic, because the only orbital remaining...is the s orbital?
I know this sounds wrong, as this does not explain the packing for elements with an electron count not in the transition series, but I am at a loss here. Is the fact that metallic atoms are treated as point charges an assumption of the metallic bonding model? Why can we ignore the organization of the lower orbitals?
EDIT: To clarify my question (I was right that it is more complicated than what Gen. Chem. says), is that metal atoms are treated as closely-packed positive point charges in metallic bonding, where delocalized d-orbital electrons can just roam around but still support strong bonds, an assumption? I know that orbitals when bonded are different from orbitals in isolated atoms, so is this tightly-packed ball model we often see just an assumption? As seen from @Jon Custer's link to the beryllium Fermi surface, it gets very complex if we look closer.

It depends what property is treated as isotropic. Conduction electrons? Fermi surface (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_surface)? Certainly, metals have different crystal structures, and a crystal is not isotropic.

Indeed, as @DrMoishePippik notes, many metals are decidedly not isotropic. Consider for example beryllium: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/538629/how-can-we-explain-that-beryllium-has-positive-charge-carriers-as-a-metal-from/538787#538787

I'm not getting your reasoning at all. Crystals, in general, are not isotropic. It doesn't really have to do with how they're packed, if they're metallic or ionic. It's just that they're ordered - this creates anisotropy of various properties, mechanical and optical in particular.

Sorry, I recently learned of CFT, and assumed the point-charge logic of that model applied to metallic bonding. However, I am still hearing the point-charge logic when it comes to metallic bonding.

It doesn't truly depend on bonding: ionic or metallic glasses are known and because they're amorphous they're also isotropic.

Your point-charge logic, when it comes to metallic bonding, isn't really accurate too. Metal isn't a salt of ions and electrons, it's more like covalent 3D network with bonds that are extremally delocalised and lack most of its directionality.

Consider it a fundamental principle that ANY science course hides more complicated things under the rug. They have to because you have to learn basics to be able to understand the more complicated stuff, and also because, well, we keep finding more complicated stuff...

@Mithoron Good point, I am assuming ionic configuration; so covalent bonds, I can assume either a hybridized orbital or some coordination complex, but how does metallic bonding act covalent? Delocalization is not sharing.

Delocalisation is pretty much embodiment of sharing - orbitals are delocalised, so the belong to many atoms. You can look up graphene with bonds delocalised on a surface, now metals are like that, but in 3D.

Even though all crystals are anisotropic, they can be compared to each other: layered materials are less isotropic than close-packed ones. In addition, bulk solid can be polycrystalline and, as a consequence, isotropic on a macroscopic scale.
When talking about metals, many resources, as you said, refer to the isotropy of some property - often electrical conductivity. The simplest metals do not have a layered structure.
The atoms, on the other hand, are not necessarily directionless at every scale. Their magnetic moments can vary in space and over time. The effects average out or not depending on what is measured.

Fcc is awfully symmetric and close packed…
